# foreach tcl list print each value in tcl and assign each value a variable in tcl list

Tags: list, variables, foreach, set, tcl

```
proc mulval { addr } {
    set lst [list [split $addr "."]]
    set lst2 [list a b c d]
    foreach i [$lst2] j [$lst] {
        set $i [$j]
        puts "$i $j"
    }
}
```

The above code is to print each value present in list i.e lst2 and $lst are printed and assigned to variable name from $lst2 and value from $lst .
The error shows in the code is "invalid command name "a b c d" "

Comment: Are you parsing an IP address? We've got a [specialist package for that in Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.html), and it knows about more of the tricky edge cases than you do.

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets are used for commands... remove them:

```
proc mulval { addr } {
    set lst [list [split $addr "."]]
    set lst2 [list a b c d]
    foreach i $lst2 j $lst {
        set $i $j
        puts "$i $j"
    }
}
```

Comment: And the `set lst [list [split …]]` looks suspicious too. I bet that `set lst [split $addr "."]` is more like what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the elements of a list, there are several ways to do so. In your code, you did something like this:

```
foreach varName {a b c d} value [split $addr .] {set $varName $value}
```

This works, but is a bit overcomplicated. This invocation does the same thing:

```
foreach {a b c d} [split $addr .] {}
# can also be written as
foreach {a b c d} [split $addr .] break
```

If you have Tcl 8.5 or later, you should use `lassign` instead:

```
lassign [split $addr .] a b c d
```

Documentation: [break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)